# Book recommendation on gravitational collapse

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, gravitational-collapse, cosmic-censorship

Does anyone know any books or lecture notes which cover the topic of gravitational collapse assuming intermediate knowledge of general relativity?

I wish it covers topics like the spherical collapse of dynamical systems, cosmic censorship problem and Cauchy problem in GR from a fairly moderate level.

Answer (score 1):

The book ["Gravitational Collapse and Spacetime Singularities"](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511536274) by Pankaj S. Joshi seems like a good place to look. The author begins with a chapter reviewing some differential geometry and general relativity, then dives into spherical collapse and cosmic censorship.

Comment: Thanks, does it also cover cauchy problem in GR?

Comment: No, I don't believe it does.